# In jinja2 for django can I check if a user is part of a group?

Tags: python, django, jinja2, django-allauth

I want to display certain header links to students and other header links to faculty. I could do what I want by checking user group in every single view, but I'd rather do it all at once in my header.html template in jinja2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by doing the test in the header template, as you say, and assigning the result to a variable there; then you can read that variable in other templates. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments

As an alternative, you could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache or http://docs.repoze.org/lru/api.html#repoze.lru.lru_cache , which would let you avoid repeated lookups without affecting the logic flow in the rest of your code.